# Serialization and concurrency

Tags: concurrency, scheme, serialization

Suppose there are two functions of x, f and g. Both change the value of x.

Case 1: Both are unserialized and are executed in parallel.

Case 2: f is serialized and g is not. They are executed in parallel.

Question:
Let all the possible values of x after the complete execution in case 1 be N.
Let all the possible values of x after the complete execution in case 2 be M.

is M equal to N?

In other words::
Is there any difference if only one of the two functions is serialized?
Unless both the functions are serialized, will there be any use of the serialization?

Comment: Is this your homework?  If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: What does "serialized" mean here?  This question is impossible to answer without more specific terms.

Comment: Its not my homework..was a question in our test..

serialized- one can be executed only after the other has ended, depending upon the order chosen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-rigorous (sorry if this is for homework ;-)) but practical answer: all mutations (i.e., both functions in your case) must be synchronised in order to have predictable results.

Answer (score 1):

As the text says,

> serialization creates distinguished sets of procedures such that only one execution of a procedure in each serialized set is permitted to happen at a time

so you need to serialize both procedures that will make changes on the shared varible.

Comment: Where is this text from?

Comment: @stomy Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs Section 3.4.2. Sorry for my forgetting to add the origin. (Don't even remember that I've ever answered this question...) I guess the question had mentioned the book before and was later updated. But anyway, that's the origin.